# Android: show child view on touch event

Tags: android

Im quite new to Android dev. I'm trying to show a child view on parent view click or select. This is my code:

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:onClick="login_click">
        <ImageView
            style="@style/button_image"
            android:id="@+id/button_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/signin"
            android:contentDescription="@string/button_icon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
        <com.ontheway.app.TextViewPlus
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_login"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

At the moment the ImageView is invisible. I would like to show it on click or select of the parent RelativeLayout. I'm wondering if this can be done through the selector or do I have to do that in java and if it's better to add the ImageView dynamically or leave it in XML like now? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the onCLick attribute, your entire layout will respond to clicks. This should work fine. Whether you put the imageview here or dynamically add it in your java seems to be more personal preference rather than hard rule

Comment: Thanks for the help! I left it in XML and just set the visibility on click and it works fine :)